# SQL Server : error on column add

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to copy rows from one column to another. Execution flow is simple.

1. Check if column is exist.
2. If not - add column
3. Define cursor and populate rows for new column
4. Set column to NOT NULL.

Unfortunately I am getting this type of error. It says that column does not exist. But I've created it and committed transaction. What could be a reason? Thanks!

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 29
>   Invalid column name 'Field_Name'.

Code:

```
begin transaction;

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.columns 
                WHERE Name = N'Field_Name' and Object_ID = Object_ID(N'dbo.Table_Name'))
BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table_Name]
        ADD [Field_Name] VARCHAR(255)
END
commit;

DECLARE
    @var1 int,
    @var2 varchar(255)

DECLARE copy_cursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT id, Name
    FROM Table_Name

OPEN copy_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM copy_cursor 
    INTO @var1, @var2

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
   UPDATE Table_Name
   SET Field_Name = @var2
   WHERE id = @var1

   FETCH NEXT FROM copy_cursor 
      INTO @var1, @var2
END

CLOSE copy_cursor;
DEALLOCATE copy_cursor;

ALTER TABLE Table_Name ALTER COLUMN Field_name varchar(255) NOT NULL
```

Comment: If the table doesn't exist how can you add a column?

Comment: If the table doesn't exist it's kind of hard to add something to it :)

Comment: Sorry. If column does not exist

Comment: As for the SQL nothing looks wrong to me, other than I don't use semi-colons in my SQL and I would use `FAST FORWARD` declared for my cursor and have a `GO` after committing my transaction :)
`SQL Server utilities interpret GO as a signal that they should send the current batch of Transact-SQL statements to an instance of SQL Server.` [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx)

Comment: Recreated the problem on my end. Using GO after comitting should solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server tries to compile an entire *batch* of SQL before it runs any of it. So, before referencing the column in a query, you need to create it (if necessary) in a *separate* batch. Insert a `GO` keyword to instruct your tool (SQLCMD, OSQL, SSMS) to send separate batches:

```
begin transaction;

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.columns 
                WHERE Name = N'Field_Name' and Object_ID = Object_ID(N'dbo.Table_Name'))
BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table_Name]
        ADD [Field_Name] VARCHAR(255)
END
commit;
GO
```

I think you may also need to wrap the `ALTER` as follows, to deal with the case where the column *does* exist:

```
        EXEC sp_executesql 'ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table_Name]
        ADD [Field_Name] VARCHAR(255)'
```

Answer (score 0):

First check if the table exists, start and commit the transaction, and it should work.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

    IF (Object_ID(N'dbo.Table_Name') > 0)
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.columns 
                      WHERE Name = N'Field_Name' and Object_ID = Object_ID(N'dbo.Table_Name'))
        BEGIN
            ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table_Name]
            ADD [Field_Name] VARCHAR(255)
        END
    END

COMMIT
GO
```